# How hard is it to approximate distance of linear code

Tags: np-hardness, approximation-hardness, coding-theory

I'm trying to figure out what is the current knowledge about how hard it is, given a generating matrix of a linear code over a field $F_{q}$, approximate it's distance.

I of course found that calculating the distance in exact is NP-Hard and that even [Approximate it to any constant factor is hard](http://madhu.seas.harvard.edu/papers/1999/dms-journ.pdf) (under randomized reductions).

However, this result is a bit old, and I didn't manage to find any newer hardness of approximation result.

I also didn't manage to find any polynomial approximation algorithms to this problem (for any factor) - all the works I found are either [deal with specific code families](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4081011_On_the_computation_of_the_minimum_distance_of_low-density_parity-check_codes) or even [don't relate to a promised gap approximation and bring only huristic/paractical result as a proof to the algorithm worthyness](https://www.issac-conference.org/2018/posters/file05.pdf)

Did my search miss something? Is there any current work that relates to this problem for a gap between constant and the trivial linear gap, and proves inapproximability /shows approximation for this gap?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe @NoahStephens-Davidowitz can help here. This [recent paper](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2019/159/) contains some new hardness results for MDP, and references to older work. For example, it is known that no $2^{(\log n)^{1-\varepsilon}}$ factor approximation is possible unless NP is contained in quasi-polynomial time (see, e.g., https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.1481.pdf).